# Cross-platform solution for Arial font

Tags: java, swing, fonts

In my Swing application I use Arial font. Unfortunately it is rendered differently on different platforms:

Windows:

[image: Windows variant]

Mac OS X:

[image]

Linux:

[image]

Windows and Mac OS X variants look almost the same. Linux is quite different and seems to be not an Arial at all. Main problem is the different width of letters...

What would be the best solution that would render text similar to Windows variant on Linux? Probably some alternative fonts like for example Nimbus Sans L?

Some limitations: JRE cannot be supplied with the application and it should be very close to Arial.

Thanks!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/C6NcGP0t
You can use that to then switch out the fonts, or else you could just save it as an image and buffer an image instead.

Comment: If you want to be cross-platform, do not insist on the same font. And why should you?

Comment: @Raedwald, main reason: letter width breaks layout at some places.

Comment: *"breaks layout"*  Fix the layout.

Comment: Layout is already OK and not under discussion. Please stick to the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution may be load the font file using `Font.createFont()`. [Here's](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-298.html) a sample.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is allowed by the Arial license? I think it must be bought before it can be bundled into an application.

Comment: I think you will have to find a free font to use. [Arial font license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) says that you cannot distribute the font. But there are many free fonts in the web, I have sure that you will find something that fits :)

Comment: Don't want to buy that domain!

Answer (score 5):

*Embrace platform variety*. Given that different platforms have similar fonts with different metrics, let each component do the work of calculating its own [*preferred size*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) by not interfering and by using layouts correctly. Here's a nice [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/230513) with screenshots.

Comment: As an aside, choosing a _logical_ font like [`Font.SANS_SERIF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#SANS_SERIF), rather than a _physical_ font like _Ariel_, is a convenient way to get the platform designer's best choice.

Comment: But I am using custom look and feel. And at some places absolute layout is used. It's not an option for me to switch to a layout manager. BTW screenshots from your example show an ugly and unergonomic design.

Comment: Is your application intended to work on more than one platform?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try antialiasing, like this article
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/renderinghints.html

Comment: Yes, actually it is enabled on example images. And antialiasing does not affect the width of letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Microsoft's free fonts on Linux and use them in Java. This includes an Arial font. This blog post shows you how: [How to Install Windows Fonts in Java on Linux](http://www.perfectabstractions.com/blog/how-to-install-windows-fonts-in-java-on-linux)